# How can I to put two values on a html list and after that read only one for displaying in a <p>{{ }}</p>

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I to put two values on a html list and after that read only one for displaying in a
`<p>{{ ? }}</p>` ?

```
<option *ngFor="let pdcSol of this.readSolHeatPumps" [value]="[pdcSol.denumire, pdcSol.cod]">{{ pdcSol.denumire }}</option>

<p>{{  this.formSol.controls['modelPDC'].value }}</p>
```

In this case on the paragraph I will have both options but I want to show only one of them..

Thank you!

Comment: `{{  this.formSol.controls['modelPDC'].value }}` <-- this won't work. Besides, can you please clarify the expected output? It's extremely unclear to me.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstood. I use reactive forms and if I pass that value, output is a string formed by that two values (pdcSol.denumire, pdcSol.cod) but I want to use in a place one value and in another the other value.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `[value]="[pdcSol.denumire, pdcSol.cod]"` will have unpredictable effect, because native `value` supports only string inputs, while you are mapping it to two-element array. In following example I replace it with some generic `id` value just for example.

Try to extract selected value from control:

```
<select #ctrl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="someVariable">
    <option *ngFor="let pdcSol of this.readSolHeatPumps" [ngValue]="pdcSol.id">{{ pdcSol.denumire }}</option>
</select>
```

And in template try to access it:

```
<p>{{ ctrl.value }}</p>
```

Beside that I assume you are using reactive forms, then the selected value shall b accessible in `select` referring control. However, your questin and code snippets are quite blurry to be hones

### EDIT

Assumption was made, that you wish to display *selected* value from the list, because you did not clarify it.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstood. Yes, I use reactive forms and if I pass that value, indeed output is a string formed by that two values (pdcSol.denumire, pdcSol.cod).

Comment: so if for some reason you really wish to pass array as option value, you can use `ngValue`, which supports objects. Otherwise, to kip it simple, stick to native `value`. Then selected value is available in controller variable binded to this control under `value` property.